# Is a collection with flatMap a monad?

Tags: scala, monads

Scala has the trait `Iterable[A]` that defines

```
def flatMap[B](f: (A) ⇒ GenTraversableOnce[B]): Iterable[B]
```

That certainly *looks* like the bind function on a monad, and the documentation hints that it is a monad, but there are two objections, one minor and one major:

- the minor one: the return-type of the function passed in is this `GenTraversableOnce`.  I think this is just a convenience that can be overlooked when judging monad-ness.
- the major one: the "value" of the monad is the list of all the values it contains, but the function is given the values one at a time.

Do these problems break the monad-ness of the collection?

Comment: A relevant question is does Scala per se (excluding scalaz) have native monads and what are some examples?  Answers would depend on how respondents choose to define a monad. Odersky's point is that they have additonal requirements for compatibility with object  orientation in Scala. In that sense the Scala concept of monad is unique to Scala and mabye saying "monad like" would be more appropriate. However, since the discussion is about Scala, you introduced the term monad in that context and it has been reasonably defined for Scala by Odersky, there is no need to qualify it in responses.

Comment: note that this isn't even the type signature of flatMap which is defined in TraversableLike, it is: `def flatMap[B, That](f: (A) ⇒ GenTraversableOnce[B])(implicit bf: CanBuildFrom[Iterable[A], B, That]): That` see: https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.11.x/src/library/scala/collection/TraversableLike.scala#L249-L254

Comment: relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25361203/what-exactly-makes-option-a-monad-in-scala/25361305#25361305

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The "major" concern is easier to answer: no, it doesn't, because that's not what it means. A monad is not required to have any particular "value" or none, only to compose with functions in particular ways.

For the "minor" one, you're right to be concerned about the types. Properly, a monad is a monoid (with some additional constraints), meaning it's a set with certain operations. The elements of this set are, as far as I can tell, things of type `A => M[B]` (in scalaz this type is called `Kleisli`); `flatMap` is the `|+|` operation of the monoid.

Does the set of *all possible* `A => Iterable[B]` in Scala form a monoid with respect to this operation (and a suitable choice of identity)? No, very much not, because there are plenty of possible `A => Iterable[B]` that violate the monad laws. For a trivial example, `{a: A => throw new RuntimeException()}`. A more serious example is that e.g. if a `Set` is present in a `flatMap` chain, this can break associativity: suppose we have:

```
f: String => Iterable[String] = {s => List(s)}
g: String => Iterable[String] = {s => Set(s)}
h: String => Iterable[String] = {s => List("hi", "hi")}
```

Then

```
((f |+| g) |+| h).apply("hi") = List("hi") flatMap h = List("hi", "hi")
```

but

```
(f |+| (g |+| h)).apply("hi") = List("hi") flatMap {s => Set("hi")} = List("hi")
```

which is upsetting, because the whole point of a monoid is that we can write `f |+| g |+| h` and not worry about which way we evaluate it. Going back to monads, the point is that we should be able to write

```
for {
  a <- f("hi")
  b <- g(a)
  c <- h(b)
} yield c
```

and not worry about which order the `flatMap`s are composed in. But for the `f`, `g` and `h` from above, which answer do you expect the above code to give? (I know the answer, but it's quite surprising). With a true monad, the question wouldn't come up except as a scala compiler implementation detail, because the answer would be the same either way.

On the other hand, does *a particular subset of* possible `A => M[B]`, e.g. "the set of all `A => List[B]` implemented under the [scalazzi safe subset of scala](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uEEhJ.png)", form a monad with respect to that definition of `flatMap`? Yes (at least for the commonly accepted definition of when two scala functions are equal). And there are several subsets for which this applies. But I think it's not entirely true to say that scala `Iterable`s *in general* form a monad under `flatMap`.

Comment: (1) `{a: A => throw new RuntimeException()}` With this example in hand, you can argue that monads do not exist in Scala at all. (2) "if a Set is present in a flatMap" A monadic operation is only monadic if the monad at both sides of it is the same. `A.flatMap(somethingorothertharterurnsB)` is *not* subject to monad laws. Monad laws for `A` are only concerned with functions that return `A`.

Comment: 1) I prefer to think of it as "only certain subsets of possible Scala functions (e.g. the scalazzi safe subset) form monads". It's an important thing to bear in mind, particularly for people coming from e.g. Haskell. 2) The question asks about `Iterable`; `List` and `Set` are both subtypes of that.

Comment: Ah OK. Iterable is not a monad of course. It's not even a collection. Its subtypes may be (different) monads.

Answer (score 18):

The answer to your headline question is ***maybe***. A collection with `flatMap` is not sufficient to be a monad, but it *might* be a monad if it satisfies some further conditions.

Your "minor" issue certainly breaks the monadicity (the proper word for "monad-ness") of `Iterable`. This is because many subtypes of `Iterable` and `GenTraversableOnce` are *not monads*. Therefore, `Iterable` is not a monad.

Your "major" issue is not a problem at all. For example, the function argument to the `List` monad's `flatMap` receives the elements of the `List` one at a time. Each element of the list generates a whole list of results, and those lists are all concatenated together at the end.

Fortunately, judging whether something is a monad is really easy! We just have to know the precise definition of *monad*.

#### The requirements for being a monad

1. A monad has to be a type constructor `F[_]` that takes one type argument. For example, `F` could be `List`, `Function0`, `Option`, etc.
2. A monadic *unit*. This is a function that takes a value of any type `A` and produces a value of type `F[A]`.
3. A monadic *composition* operation. It's an operation that takes a function of type `A => F[B]`, and a function of type `B => F[C]` and produces a composite function of type `A => F[C]`.

(There are other ways of stating this, but I find this formulation straightforward to explain)

Consider these for `Iterable`. It definitely takes one type argument. It has a unit of sorts in the function `Iterable(_)`. And while its `flatMap` operation doesn't strictly conform, we could certainly write:

```
def unit[A](a: A): Iterable[A] = Iterable(a)

def compose[A,B,C](f: A => Iterable[B],
                   g: B => Iterable[C]): A => Iterable[C] =
  a => f(a).flatMap(g)
```

But this does not make it a monad, since a monad additionally has to satisfy certain *laws*:

1. Associativity: `compose(compose(f, g), h)` = `compose(f, compose(g, h))`
2. Identity: `compose(unit, f)` = `f` = `compose(f, unit)`

An easy way to break these laws, [as lmm has already pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27754385/3434), is to mix `Set` and `List` as the `Iterable` in these expressions.

#### "Semimonads"

While a type construction with just `flatMap` (and not `unit`), is not a monad, it may form what's called a *Kleisli semigroupoid*. The requirements are the same as for *monad*, except without the `unit` operation and without the identity law.

(A note on terminology: A monad forms a *Kleisli category*, and a *semigroupoid* is a category without identities.)

#### For-comprehensions

Scala's for-comprehensions technically have even *fewer* requirements than semigroupoids (just `map` and `flatMap` operations obeying *no* laws). But using them with things that are not at least semigroupoids has very strange and surprising effects. For example, it means that you can't inline definitions in a for-comprehension. If you had

```
val p = for {
  x <- foo
  y <- bar
} yield x + y
```

And the definition of `foo` were

```
val foo = for {
  a <- baz
  b <- qux
} yield a * b
```

Unless the associativity law holds, we *cannot* rely on being able to rewrite this as:

```
val p = for {
  a <- baz
  b <- qux
  y <- bar
} yield a * b + y
```

Not being able to do this kind of substitution is extremely counterintuitive. So most of the time when we work with for-comprehensions we assume that we're working in a monad (likely even if we're not aware of this), or at least a Kleisli semigroupoid.

But note that *this kind of substitution does not work in general for `Iterable`*:

```
scala> val bar: Iterable[Int] = List(1,2,3)
bar: Iterable[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)

scala> val baz: Iterable[Int] = Set(1,2,3)
baz: Iterable[Int] = Set(1, 2, 3)

scala> val qux: Iterable[Int] = List(1,1)
qux: Iterable[Int] = List(1, 1)

scala> val foo = for {
     |   x <- bar
     |   y <- baz
     | } yield x * y
foo: Iterable[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 6, 3, 6, 9)

scala> for {
     |   x <- foo
     |   y <- qux
     | } yield x + y
res0: Iterable[Int] = List(2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 3, 3, 5, 5, 7, 7, 4, 4, 7, 7, 10, 10)

scala> for {
     |   x <- bar
     |   y <- baz
     |   z <- qux
     | } yield x * y + z
res1: Iterable[Int] = List(2, 3, 4, 3, 5, 7, 4, 7, 10)
```

#### For more information about monads

For more on monads in Scala, including what it all *means* and why we should care, I encourage you to have a look at [chapter 11 of my book.](http://manning.com/bjarnason)

Comment: Am I correct in thinking that if you repaired the flaw in the type-signature, so it was `def flatMap[B](f: (A) ⇒ Iterable[B]): Iterable[B]`, that would fix associativity (ignoring covariance issues for now) and then Iterable would be a (true) Monad?  Also, I don't understand the basis for your statement, "The trick is that because *List* is a monad, the resulting lists are all concatenated."

Comment: And it also seems that Futures (which do not have a true `unit`) are not Monads, despite having an associative `bind` in `when`.

Comment: No, fixing up the type signature of `flatMap` on `Iterable` would not fix the associativity issue. The core issue is that two `Iterable` instances may have different semantics for `flatMap`.

Comment: Futures definitely do have a `unit`. If you have a value of some type `A`, you can always turn that into a `Future[A]` that just returns that value.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question in the context of core Scala excluding Scalaz and category theory, while core Scala does not have a trait, class or object named "Monad", it does implement an object-oriented concept of monad that I will reference as Orderskian monad, since it was invented and implemented primarily by Martin Ordersky (and Adrian Moors according to http://igstan.ro/posts/2012-08-23-scala-s-flatmap-is-not-haskell-s.html).

An Orderskian monad requires at least map, flatmap and withFilter functions as explained in "Programming In Scala" (2Ed:PDF edition:chapter 23:page 531) by Martin Odersky where he states "Therefore, map, flatMap and withFilter can be seen as an object-oriented version of the functional concept of monad." Based on this, Scala Collections are Orderskian monads.

To answer your question including Scalaz, it requires a scalaz.Monad implementatation to extend the Monad trait and implement two abstract functions, pure and bind, in order to satisfy three laws requiring them (http://scalaz.github.io/scalaz/scalaz-2.9.1-6.0.2/doc/index.html#scalaz.Monad). Core Scala collections do not meet those requirements so  nothing could ever break their scalaz.Monad-ness because it never existed. To the extent that scalaz.Monad models category theory monad, this argument applies to the latter.

Comment: People are downvoting this. Why?  Is it the discrepancy between the formal definition of Monad in category theory and Odersky's definition of the Monad class?

Comment: I could not say and am going with Odersky. If someone has a better answer let them put it up. Scala per se does not have an actual Monad trait or class - that is in scalaz.

Comment: I'm upvoting but would just correct this: a monad does not need flatmap and map as map can be expressed in term of flatmap and unit anyway (as far as I remember from Functional Programming in Scala)

Comment: Odersky is a co-author of the paper Parametric type classes
 https://scholar.google.com.hk/scholar?cluster=1161602674140322104&as_sdt=0,5

, in which they created a definition for Haskell monad. So oderskian monad is actually Haskell monad.

Answer (score 2):

I think a collection with a flatMap is not necessarily a monad. It does not necessarily fit the [monad laws](http://eed3si9n.com/learning-scalaz/Monad+laws.html). These laws are probably better explained in [Functional Programming in Scala](http://www.manning.com/bjarnason/) than I could do.

Recently I heard from a coworker a simplified and pragmatic explanation (with self-consciousness) of what is a monad in Scala: `something you can put in a for comprehension`.

I'm not a monad expert, but it seems to me that this is not true, and so it is for collections with flatMap. The most obvious exemple of this is in Scala lib `Either` as it is not right biaised and it does not have any flatMap method until you project it to a side (and this projection is not monadic as it returns Either). As far as I understand it, a type is not a monad (or a monoid or whatever), but a type may have a monad (or even many ones? not sure but would be interested by any exemple (but maybe Either is the good one?)).

I think Scala is a pragmatic language, in which it can sometimes be useful to forget about strict rules and help programmers to do their job more easily. Not all programmers care about what is a monad, but many probably want to flatten a `List[Set[Int]]` at some point and flatMap may help them.

This reminds me of this blog post in which the [Future type is considered as copointed for tests](http://logji.blogspot.fr/2014/02/the-abstract-future.html).

Comment: I almost fully rephrased my answer. Ch29 of Programming in Scala 2ed is "For Expressions Revisited". It is about determining the functions necessary to support the full range of for expressions and loops in order to enable their translation using those functions. This is why withFilter is necessary. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15149738/direct-translation-of-haskell-monad-into-scala for monad implementations in core scala without scalaz.

Answer (score 1):

Scala collection methods flatMap and flatten are more powerful than monadic flatMap/flatten. See here: https://www.slideshare.net/pjschwarz/scala-collection-methods-flatmap-and-flatten-are-more-powerful-than-monadic-flatmap-and-flatten

[image]